# In a nested loop two different Datatables get the same result set and raised an exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I am facing an error **"Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute."**. I solved this issue somehow but now it is taking comparatively longer time to display results.
I am working on Chart of Accounts, and want to show it in a WPF TREEVIEW. It involved 5 external SQL tables.
First time it populate the **DataTable dt1** with Classcode table, when the row in Classcode had any child, it populate the next table GroupCode in **Datatable dt2**.

When it comes back to pickup the next row in **DataTable dt1**, the dt1 is now changed and populated with the resultset of dt2. I am unable to understand why it loads the dt2 resultset. Here the Exception raised: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.".
Please help.

Here is how I am working:

`Coa.xaml`

```
<TreeView Name="trVwAccounts"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
            xmlns:obj="clr-namespace:Arhat.Views" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type obj:Accounts}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="Auto"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

`Coa.xaml.cs`

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        public Coa()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UpdateTView();
        }
        public void UpdateTView()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Accounts> Souce = new ObservableCollection<Accounts>();

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /// ClassCode
            /// 
            qry1 = "SELECT * FROM ClassCode ORDER BY ClassID";

            dt1.Clear();
            dt1 = con.QryData(qry1);
            foreach (DataRow rowc in dt1.Rows.To)
            {
                ttl = rowc["ClassName"].ToString().Trim();
                id = rowc["ClassID"].ToString().Trim();
                int nng = Int32.Parse(rowc["Sr"].ToString()); //How many children it may have
                P11 = new CoAccounts() { Title = id + ": " + ttl };
                P1.Children.Add(P11);

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                /// GroupCode
                /// 
                if (nng > 0)
                {
                    qry2 = "SELECT * FROM GroupCode WHERE ClassID= " + id + " ORDER BY GroupID";
                    dt2.Clear();
                    dt2 = con.QryData(qry2);
                    int cntig = dt2.Rows.Count;
                    if (cntig > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow rowg in dt2.Rows)
                        {
                            ttl = rowg["GroupName"].ToString().Trim();
                            id = rowg["GroupID"].ToString().Trim();
                            int nnc = Int32.Parse(rowg["Sr"].ToString()); //How many children it may have

                            P111 = new CoAccounts() { Title = id + ": " + ttl };
                            P11.Children.Add(P111);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Souce.Add(P1);
            trVwAccounts.ItemsSource = Souce;
        }
```

`And the Accounts Class`

```
    public class Accounts
    {
        public Accounts()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<Accounts>();
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Accounts> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Ok, Let me ask this question in another way:
ّWhen I run these lines below:

```
            DBCon con = new DBCon();
            qry1 = "SELECT * FROM ClassCode ORDER BY ClassID";
            dt1 = con.QryData(qry1);
            qry2 = "SELECT * FROM GroupCode WHERE ClassID = 1 ORDER BY GroupID";
            dt2 = con.QryData(qry2);

and my QryData(qry) function in DBCon Class:

   class DBCon
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public DataTable QryData(string query)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    dt.Clear();
                    for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[i];
                        dt.Columns.Remove(dc);
                    }
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    return dt;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

I got **dt1** and **dt2** have the same result set, means dt1 have the result set of qry2, WHY?
dt1 and dt2 must have separate results, because these are populated from two different queries. How can I get two different results?
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this your entire code? The error cannot conceivably arise from this.

Comment: Unrelated: avoid using string concatenation to create queries: aside from the risk of SQL injection vulnerability, it can lead to syntax errors.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, I have updated my question, please read the last portion.

Comment: What is `dt` in `QryData`? You still have not shared full code. I believe it is a member variable so both dt1 and dt2 get to point to same object.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, dt is DataTable declared before this QryData function. It has no issue and working properly.

Comment: I disagree, `dt` is the cause of your problems.

Comment: I have updated my question a bit to show where i declare **dt**.

Comment: Let me try your solution, let you know shortly.

Comment: Thank you very much Bro. It is working as expected. I have accepted it as answer and tried to make **This answer is useful**, but score is still 0, it once raised to 1 and then become 0 again. Anyhow thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are reusing `dt` member variable and everything ends up pointing to the same object.

Modify your `QryData()` to be this

```
    public DataTable QryData(string query)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
        return new DataTable();
    }
```

Although, `Console.WriteLine` in catch blocks and hiding exceptions with a final `return` is bad practice.